# Git pull and push is not worked

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, apache2, ssh-keys

I don't understand why this command does't worked. Does Anybody have this situation is happened?

**Params**:
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
php.7.4.7
git version 2.17.1

```
git status, git checkout, git branch
```

is worked but `git pull origin master, git push origin master` is not worked. I don't find the answer on google.

Error:

> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

**EDIT:**
I found this but it doesn't work me: [link](https://gist.github.com/Tamal/1cc77f88ef3e900aeae65f0e5e504794)
I got a timeout error:

> ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection timed out
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Plz, help me

Comment: could you post more  details, such as output/error message from git.

Comment: @CQLI thank reply. added error message too

Comment: Another possibility is that you have added the ssh key under the project, not under the user profile. Can you please check that too.

Comment: @AbhilashPS thanks answer, it worked on its own

Answer (score 1):

First I would check

`git remote show origin`

to make sure the URL is correct.

If the URL is correct, then you probably don't have permissions to edit that repository. Follow [these instructions](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to add an SSH key to you Github account.

Comment: I have a remote. I did git pull and  git push before problem appeared

Comment: What happens when you run `ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is happened but it was worked on its own. And I found a useful link below:

1. [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Tamal/1cc77f88ef3e900aeae65f0e5e504794)
2. [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610940/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-refused)